# php best practices

Tags: php

i came across this page on php structure at [here](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/php/guide.php). i tho it was good but i wanna know what others think about this and is there any improvement that can be implemented??

Comment: Yet another guide that newbies should not read ever.

Comment: hmm and why is that so??

Comment: Note that the page has this date: [2005-7-11]. Since there'are tons of similar pages and suggestions, my 2 cents: go for updated ones (which can incorporate design patterns like MVC, for example), and always give preminence to those who focus on security

Comment: yeah the guide is all ok. but look very outdated. now is very easy implement all of that best practices using some php framework like Zend, Yii, cake and others.

Comment: Damn, too late with my reply. :) But in short: yes, it is outdated.

Comment: Though I cannot agree or disagree with any of comments above, **but** I think that every newbie should reinvent the best practices. It is the only way that will help brand new developer to learn how to think and how to program, instead of just blidnly following to the advices from "that one article"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website looks very outdated and the information is disputeable.

Register globals is a thing of the past.

Short opening tags are absolutely fine if you have control over your server.

Having only one single configuration file can be very annoying too.

In a lot of MVC structures its exactly the other way round.

In most web application it has proven to be useful to have a single point of entry (a bootstrap file) and an object oriented structure with common naming conventions. Global functions are not really up2date any more when using such a structure.

Static helper classes are used a lot.

I would say if you choose the object oriented style the default object oriented paradigms apply. Try to have essential functionalities close together. Have your code organised, reasonable and understandable. Eliminate dependencies across your program. Try not to have redundant code so you can change behaviour of your application at single points.

Focus on performance.

Comment: Hey tks joe, this helps. i take note of that. =)

Comment: "Focuse on performance." --- this could give him idea of optimizations like `' is faster than ", or echo $a,$b is better echo $a.$b`. I would say "focus on design" since, good designed code - is the code that can be modified (for any purposes) easy.

Comment: wat do you guys think about the VO and DAO?

Comment: @zerkms +1 to *focus on design*.

Comment: Both VO and DAO have their place and uses. Just make sure you really DO understand what these uses are. There's no point introducing such classes just for the sake of introducing them.